# React native : Json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structure

Tags: react-native

The issue happened here while using canvas property.

I tried to create roulette in react native using canvas property. I successfully used canvas, except I cannot use `ctx.drawImage` methods. When I tried to use them I got an error like

> JSON.Stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures

Here is a code snipet

```
            componentDidMount(){
            wheelCanvas = this.updateCanvas();
    }

// This is in error while rendering : 

            ctx.drawImage(wheelCanvas, wheelCanvas.width / 2, wheelCanvas.height / 2);

            updateCanvas() {
            var outsideRadius = 120;
            var textRadius = 100;
            var insideRadius = 30;
            var canvas = this.refs.canvasRoulette;
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = canvas.height = outsideRadius * 2 + 6;

            var x = outsideRadius + 3;
            var y = outsideRadius + 3;

            ctx.font = "bold 18px Helvetica, Arial";

            for (var i = 0; i < rouletteSize; i++) {
              var angle = i * arc;
              ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(x, y, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
              ctx.arc(x, y, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
              ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
              ctx.lineWidth = 1;
              ctx.stroke();
              ctx.fill();
              ctx.save();
              ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
              ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
              ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
              ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(220,220,220)";
              ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
              ctx.translate(
                x + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
                y + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius
              );

              ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI);
              var text = numbers[i];
              ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 5);
              ctx.restore();
            }
            return canvas;
            }
```

Comment: this usually happen when json is cyclic like a:{b} , b:{a}

Comment: where are you using JSON.Stringify ?  also, what is ctx, is it a canvas ref to something? please add your complete code so we can have a better look.